# Charts and atlases under "extrinsic" and "intrinsic" view

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, definition

I'm getting a bit confused about a conceptual question.
Consider a differentiable manifold (e.g. a 2-sphere)...reading the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Patchwork) article, it seems that we'll end up with defining different types of charts whenever we look at the manifold from the *extrinsic* or the *intrinsic* viewpoint. However, reading other sources, there's no such difference.

Moreover, even if the intrinsic approach is usually described as "coordinates-free", it however relies on the definition of coordinate charts (and transition maps).

Where am I lost?

Comment: A manifold may admit many different atlases; the definition of a manifold isn't a space equipped with a particular choice of atlases. Some people like to talk about maximal atlases for this reason, because those are unique.

Comment: Ok @QiaochuYuan, but even if just the maximal atlas is unique, the two atlases described in the Wiki article seem to depend on the choice of our viewpoint on a manifold - is it so?

Comment: I'm not sure what atlases you're referring to, but in general, picking an embedding of a manifold into Euclidean space may be a convenient way to write down charts, but once you've written those charts down you don't need to remember the embedding anymore, you've already got your charts.

Comment: Maybe mine is just a formal problem, but, still taking in account the 2-sphere example from Wiki, in the "extrinsic view case" we get an atlas made up of charts that map to two discs in $\mathbb R ^2$, whereas in the "intrinsic view scenario" the mapping is to two copies of $\mathbb R ^2$...is this a significative difference, or I am wrong more deeply?

Comment: This is not a significant difference; the open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Whether you prefer your charts to involve open disks in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a matter of convenience, the theory is the same either way, and this has nothing to do with the intrinsic vs. extrinsic distinction.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Just to be sure, are you saying that also the "patchwork construction" could end up with a diffeomorphism to open disks instead of $\mathbb R ^2$?

Comment: Yep, it's the same either way.